# A Scalable Architecture for Reconstructing events

Tags: java, architecture, jvm, replay

I have been tasked to develop the architecture for a data transformation pipeline.
Essentially, data comes in at one end and is routed through various internal systems acquiring different forms before ending up in its destination.

> The main objectives are -
>
> - **Fault Tolerant**. The message should be recoverable if one of the intermediate systems were down.
> - **Replay/ Resequence**  - The message can be replayed from any stage and it should be possible to recreate the events in an idempotent manner.

I have a few custom solutions in mind to address

- Implement a checkpoint system where a message can be logged at both entry and exit points at each checkpoint so we know where failure happens.
- Implement a recovery mechanism that can go to the logged storage ( database, log file etc.. ) and reconstruct events programmatically.

However, I have a feeling this is a fairly standard problem with well defined solutions.

So, I would welcome any thoughts on a suitable architecture to go with, any tools/packages/patterns to refer to etc..

Thanks

Comment: Do you still need replay ability if messages can not be lost in transit? That is, do you need replay just to process lost messages, or it is there an actual business reason to roll back the system to a previous state?

Comment: There is no usecase for rolling back the system to a previous state. Its mainly to replay lost messages from wherever they were lost.

Answer (score 1):

[Akka](http://akka.io/) is obvious choice. Of course Scala version is more powerful, but even with Java bindings you can achieve a lot.

I think you can follow [CQRS](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/CQRS.html) approach and use [Akka Persistence](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/persistence.html) module. In this case it's easy to replay any sequence of events, because you always have a persistent journal.

Generally Actor Model provides you fault-tolerance using [supervision](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/java/fault-tolerance.html).

[Akka Clustering](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.3.9/common/cluster.html) will give you scalability you need.

Really awesome example of using Akka Clustering with Akka Persistence and Cassandra - https://github.com/boldradius/akka-dddd-template (only Scala unfortunately).

Answer (score 0):

One common solution is [JMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service), where a central component (the JMS Broker) keeps a transactional store of pending messages. Because it does nothing other than that, it can have a high uptime (uptime can further be increased with a failover cluster, in which case you'll likely its persistence store to be a failover cluster, too).

Sending a JMS message can be made transactional, as can consuming a message. These transaction can be synchronized with database transactions through XA-transactions, which does its utmost get as close to exactly-once delivery as possible, but is rather heavy machinery.

In many cases (idempotent receiver), at-least-once delivery is sufficient. This can be accomplished by sending the message with a synchronous transaction (that is, the sender only succeeds once the broker has acknowledged receipt of the message), and consuming a message only after it has been processed.